# Explicit form for solutions x in $\operatorname{Erfc}(-x) = a \cdot e^{-x^2}$

Tags: error-function

I'm looking for closed form of points where $\operatorname{Erfc}(-x)$ intersects with $a \cdot e^{-x^2}$ for $a$ being some fixed non-zero constant.

I guess I can use the exponential approximation for $\operatorname{Erfc}$. Then I probably can find closed form with help of Lambert W function.
But I wonder if solution can be found without any use of approximations for $\operatorname{Erfc}$.

Comment: Can we assume that $a \ge 0$?

Comment: Thank you for comment! Yes, I think it's ok. We can can assume $a \geq 0$.

Comment: Totally revised.

Comment: Much improved. Have a look at the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that you want to find the inverse of
$$a=e^{x^2} (1+\text{erf}(x))$$ which, I suppose, does not show any closed form solution.

Better is to consider instead the problem of the inverse of
$$b=\log\Big(e^{x^2} (1+\text{erf}(x))\Big) \quad \text{with} \quad b=\log(a)$$

What we can  notice is that $\large\color{red}{x_0=\sqrt b}$ is a decent approximation. For example, for $b=4$, the "exact" solution is $1.81986$. Moreover
$$0\leq\log \left(e^b
   \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{b}\right)\right)\right)-b < \log(2)$$

By Darboux theorem, we also know that, $x_0$ being an over estimate, the solution by Newton method will converge without any overshoot. For the given example, $x_1=1.82774$, $x_2=1.81988$.

This means that we can have $\color{red}{\text{explicit}}$ approximate solutions using the first iterate of Newton-like methods of order $n$ starting at $x_0=\sqrt b$.

A few numbers for illustration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
b & x_1^{(2)} & x_1^{(3)}& x_1^{(4)}& x_1^{(5)} & \text{solution}\\
 0.5 & 0.42132 & 0.38998 & 0.38861 & 0.38872 &  0.38872 \\
 1.0 & 0.72532 & 0.69733 & 0.69579 & 0.69586 &  0.69586 \\
 1.5 & 0.97265 & 0.95039 & 0.94912 & 0.94914 &  0.94915 \\
 2.0 & 1.18365 & 1.16622 & 1.16525 & 1.16525 &  1.16525 \\
 2.5 & 1.36912 & 1.35533 & 1.35461 & 1.35460 &  1.35460\\
 3.0 & 1.53563 & 1.52454 & 1.52400 & 1.52399 &  1.52399 \\
 3.5 & 1.68751 & 1.67842 & 1.67802 & 1.67801 &  1.67801 \\
 4.0 & 1.82774 & 1.82018 & 1.81987 & 1.81986 &  1.81986 \\
 4.5 & 1.95850 & 1.95211 & 1.95186 & 1.95186 &  1.95186 \\
 5.0 & 2.08138 & 2.07589 & 2.07570 & 2.07570 &  2.07570 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

It is possible to find a better $x_0$ since the solution is such that
$$\sqrt{b-\log (2)} < x < \sqrt{b}$$

So, working an initial estimate of the form
$$x_0=\sqrt{b-\log (2) \,f(b)} $$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(\infty)=1$

Some *empirical* analysis leads to propose the simplistic
$$f(b)=\text{erf}\left(\frac{253}{321} x^{\frac 7{10}}\right)$$ This was obtained by a quick and dirty nonlinear regression for $0\leq b \leq 5$ which correspond to an adjusted $R^2=0.99995$.

Repeating the calculations only for Newton method

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
b & x_0 & x_1^{(2)}  & \text{solution}\\
 0.5 & 0.38512 & 0.38873 &  0.38872 \\
 1.0 & 0.70039 & 0.69587 &  0.69586 \\
 1.5 & 0.95028 & 0.94915 &  0.94915 \\
 2.0 & 1.16426 & 1.16525 &  1.16525 \\
 2.5 & 1.35300 & 1.35460 &  1.35460 \\
 3.0 & 1.52252 & 1.52399 &  1.52399 \\
 3.5 & 1.67689 & 1.67801 &  1.67801 \\
 4.0 & 1.81910 & 1.81986 &  1.81986 \\
 4.5 & 1.95136 & 1.95186 &  1.95186 \\
 5.0 & 2.07539 & 2.07570 &  2.07570 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @njuffa. Unknown parameters to be adjusted

Comment: Thank you for great approximation! It's pity that it is not a closed form :(

Comment: @PiotrSemenov. I am working for something which could be interesting.

Comment: @njuffa. I am sorry but I do not understand the point. Could you clarify ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @njuffa. Please, don't speak about old brains ! Mine is more than old. Yes, I am working with $b=\log(a)$. Plot the inverse function; it is really nice (even looking or less to Lambert function).

Comment: @njuffa. I felt in love 65 years ago with Taylor (series), Padé (approximants) and Lambert (function). I am still looking for good approximations of the last.  Did you publish anything in this area ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Wow! Thank you very much! Great approach! It's was really helpful.

Comment: @njuffa. If you have time to waste, have a look at the edit. Funny

Comment: @njuffa. This is a very good idea ! It took me time to find the correct bounds. The approximation was simple and I still hope to make it better. If I may ask, where are you located ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably not in the spirit of what the asker requested ("without any use of approximations for $\mathrm{Erfc}$"), but it may help the next person with a similar problem and no such restriction.

A closed-form solution does not exist. However, many computational environments provide an exponentially scaled complementary error function $e^{x^2}\mathrm{erfc}(x)$, often named `erfcx`, that one can use to compute $a$ from $x$. Where it is not provided, one could derive it from this [sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777360/accurate-computation-of-scaled-complementary-error-function-erfcx) in C that I posted on Stackoverflow some time ago.

Here we need to solve $\mathrm{erfcx}(-x) = a$, that is, compute $x = -\mathrm{erfcx}^{-1}(a)$. While $\mathrm{erfcx}^{-1}$ (named `erfcxinv`) is not typically provided as a standard function, one can easily compute it by Newton-Raphson iteration. One observes that for $x \to 0$, $\mathrm{erfcx}^{-1}(x) \approx \frac{1}{x\sqrt{\pi}}$, and that for $x \to \infty$, $\mathrm{erfcx}^{-1}(x) \approx -\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$ and can pick a starting value for the iteration process accordingly. To compute `x = erfcxinv (a)`, one proceeds as follows:

```
   c := 1 / sqrt (pi)
   IF a < 1
     x := c / a 
   ELSE
     x := -sqrt (ln (a))
   FI
   DO i = 0 to n
     e := erfcx (x)
     r := 1 / fma (x, e, -c)
     x := fma ((a - e) / 2, r, x)
   OD
```

In the above pseudocode, `fma (a,b,c) := a * b + c`, with many computational environments supplying a numerically beneficial operation called [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) under that name. For IEEE-754 double-precision computation, one might choose $n = 5$ to compute results accurate to machine precision.

Comment: Very nice answer ! I forgot to tell you that I started with computers in 1961. Some years ago, for a contest (speed was the issue) I wrote a part of the code in Assembler. Cheers :-)